# Why does CoreAnimation appear to be caching the presentation layer copy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-animation

So we are running into some interesting issues with what appears to be the caching of the presentation layer, and we are wondering if other people are seeing this, and what workarounds we can do.

We have a couple of our own properties that we are implicitly animating. We are doing this by declaring them as properties and synthesizing them dynamically:

```
@interface GOOLayer : CALayer
@property float gooValue;
@end

NSString *const kGOOLayerValueKey = @"gooValue";

@implementation GOOLayer

@dynamic gooValue;

- (id)initWithLayer:(id)layer {
  if ((self = [super initWithLayer:layer])) {
    id value = [layer valueForKey:kGOOLayerValueKey];
    [self setValue:value forKey:kGOOLayerValueKey];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)event {
  id <CAAction> action = [super actionForKey:event];
  if (action == nil && [event isEqual:kGOOLayerValueKey]) {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:event];
    animation.fromValue = [self.presentationLayer valueForKey:event];
    animation.duration =  [CATransaction animationDuration];
    return animation;
  }
  return action;
}

- (void)display {
  GOOLayer *presoLayer = [self presentationLayer];
  NSLog(@"Display GooValue: %f", presoLayer.gooValue);
}

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
  if ([key isEqual:kGOOLayerValueKey]) {
    return YES;
  }
  return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}
```

In most cases this works fine, and we see the appropriate values being logged.
In the first case, we get proper implicit animation:

```
- (IBAction)doSomeGoo:(id)sender {
  sublayer_.gooValue = random();
}
```

Output:

```
2012-12-19 10:10:41.440 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] Display GooValue: 1804289408.000000
2012-12-19 10:10:41.502 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] Display GooValue: 1804289408.000000
...
2012-12-19 10:10:41.739 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] Display GooValue: 898766464.000000
2012-12-19 10:10:41.757 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] Display GooValue: 846930880.000000
```

In the second case, we disable the actions so we get a single value update which is fine:

```
- (IBAction)doSomeGoo2:(id)sender {
  long newValue = random();
  NSLog(@"newValue = %f", (float)newValue);
  [CATransaction begin];
  [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
  sublayer_.gooValue = newValue;
  [CATransaction commit];
}
```

First time through:

```
2012-12-19 10:11:16.208 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] newValue = 1714636928.000000
2012-12-19 10:11:16.209 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] Display GooValue: 1714636928.000000
```

Second time through:

```
2012-12-19 10:11:26.258 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] newValue = 1957747840.000000
2012-12-19 10:11:26.259 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] Display GooValue: 1957747840.000000
```

It's the third case in which we just call [CALayer presentationLayer] before we do the transaction that is interesting:

```
- (IBAction)doSomeGoo3:(id)sender {
  GOOLayer *presoLayer = sublayer_.presentationLayer;
  long newValue = random();
  NSLog(@"presoLayer.gooValue = %f newValue = %f", presoLayer.gooValue, (float)newValue);
  [CATransaction begin];
  [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
  sublayer_.gooValue = newValue;
  [CATransaction commit];
}
```

First time through:

```
2012-12-19 10:12:12.505 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] presoLayer.gooValue = 1957747840.000000 newValue = 424238336.000000
2012-12-19 10:12:12.505 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] Display GooValue: 1957747840.000000
```

Second time through:

```
2012-12-19 10:12:13.905 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] presoLayer.gooValue = 424238336.000000 newValue = 719885376.000000
2012-12-19 10:12:13.906 CoreAnimation[94149:c07] Display GooValue: 424238336.000000
```

Note how the addition of the presentationLayer call makes it so that display doesn't get the current value.

Any suggestions as to how to deal with this, or if I am completely misunderstanding things, and this is expected behavior?

Answer (score 10):

I didn't access the `presentationLayer`, but still got to the same problem today.

Whenever a `UIScrollView`'s scroll bars appeared, then some animations did not work as intended. It took me hours to figure out that it is a problem related to `CATransaction` and accessing the `presentationLayer`.

Accessing the `presentationLayer` causes `CATransaction` to ignore (or defer) any commits of explicit transactions until the current runloop cycle ends. Looking at the log of messages, `+[CATransaction commit]` for explicit transactions becomes a no-op as soon as the `presentationLayer` was accessed for ANY layer.

I found two way to make these commits work again, but with negative side-effects.

1. Flushing all layer changes using `+[CATransaction flush]` updates the `presentationLayer` of all layers and makes `+[CATransaction begin…commit]` work as expected.
2. Committing the implicit transaction using `+[CATransaction commit]` yields the same result.

But as soon as I did that, other random problems occurred throughout the app. Some views were simply invisible even through they were layouted correctly and even `drawRect:` was called.
Going deeper I noticed that `UIView`'s and their backing `CALayer` became out of sync very often.

I came to the conclusion what I was wrong to rely on the `presentationLayer` for what I wanted to do.

Apple's documentation article [Core Animation Rendering Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/CoreAnimationArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006655-SW1) makes clear that `presentationLayer` has all values of the layer as they are currently visible to the user. Any changes made with or without animation won't be reflected by the `presentationLayer` until the runloop cycle ends (or the outer usually implicit `CATransaction` was flushed/committed) and all layer changes are presented to the user.

As my animations rely on changes made to the layer within the same runloop cycle, these changes are not yet visible to the user and thus not available through the `presentationLayer`.

`-[CALayer display]` should only access the layer's values and not those of its `presentationLayer`, as the examples in [Providing Layer Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/ProvidingCALayerContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006642-SW2) show.
Animations which should start from what the user currently sees can use the `presentationLayer`'s value as `fromValue`.

Any other problems which still arise are most likely due to using the rendering architecture in a wrong way.
I will rethink my animations so that they use the layer's current state instead of the `presentationLayer`'s.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @fluidsonic.   
[Core Animation Rendering Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/CoreAnimationArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006655-SW1) states explicitly that "You can query an instance of CALayer for its corresponding presentation layer while an animation transaction is in process. This is most useful if you intend to change the current animation and want to begin the new animation from the currently displayed state."  
Given what we are seeing, this would appear to be false.

Comment: I think that this statement is still valid.
//
When you call display, it outputs the gooValue which is presented to the user at exactly that moment.
//
I guess that in the last example when you query the presentationLayer earlier, it causes an implicit transactions which lasts until the current runloop cycle ends and thus the change is not immediately visible to the user.
//
Maybe you should extend your test to display the number of current runloop cycle or output whenever something was actually rendered and presented to the user (screen update).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix a similar problem by using `[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:`

that allowed the runloop to complete and update the `presentationLayer`